# Angular ajax $http cannot post and get in same time

Tags: ajax, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to use MEAN stack store and update a simple angular to do list, I've write a restful api for server.the post record function `app.addTask = function(task)` working fine if I remove `$http.get` from html, but once put it back, it stop record the new task.
Can't figure it out why, need your guys help.

Here is the server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    restful = require('node-restful'),
    bodyParser = require('body-Parser'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    mongoose = restful.mongoose;

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/transTaskDB');

//create new collection
var TaskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    contents: String,
    target: String,
    color: String,
    status: Boolean
});

var Tasks = restful.model('tasks', TaskSchema);

// Tasks.methods(['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']);

// Tasks.register(app, '/api/tasks');


// ROUTES FOR OUR API
//===============================================
var router = express.Router();  //get an instance of express Router

// middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    console.log('Shown when each request made.');
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});

//custom filter find the last entry record
//record new task
router.route('/newtask')
    .post(function(req, res){
        //create a new instance of the task model
        var task = new Tasks();
        task.contents = req.body.taskContent;
        task.target = req.body.taskUser;
        task.color = req.body.taskColor;
        // task.contents = "have a tea";
        // task.target = "tony";
        // task.color = "#e74c3c";
        task.status = false; //** fasle means the task still open not done
        //task.save();
        //throw error exception in console
        task.save(function(err, tasks) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(tasks);
        });
    })

    .get(function(req, res){
        Tasks.find(function(err, tasks) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(tasks);
        });
    });


//REGISTER OUT ROUTES --------
//all of our route will be prefixed with /api
app.use('/api/tasks', router);

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server is running at port 3000');
```

html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en' ng-app='TaskAPP'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Trans Task</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='bower_components/bootstrap-sass/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='bower_components/bootstrap-sass/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url('images/swirl_pattern.png');
            background-repeat: repeat-y repeat-x;
        }
        .done {text-decoration: line-through; color: #ccc;}
        .task-list {list-style: none;}
        .published-list {
            padding: 10px 40px;
        }
        .published-list >div {
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            font-size:20px;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower"></span> Trans Task
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div ng-controller='taskCtrl as app'>
        <form role="form" name='frm2' ng-submit="app.addTask(app.task)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Task Contains</label>
                <input type='text' name='taskInput' class='form-control' ng-model="app.task.taskContent" placeholder="Enter task" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <!--need find a way to load the registed users from mongodb-->
                <!--apply socket.io on each individual user to get realtime task update and update manager the roger response-->
                <label>Target assign to</label>
                <input type='text' name='taskInput' class='form-control' ng-model="app.task.taskUser" placeholder="Enter name" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>with color</label>
                <select ng-model="app.task.taskColor">
                    <option ng-repeat="col in colors" value="{{col.color}}" >{{col.title}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled='frm2.$invalid'>Publish</button>
        </form>

        <ul class='task-list'>
            <li class="published-list" ng-repeat="tsk in app.task">
                <div ng-style={'background-color':tsk.color}>
                    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='tsk.status'>
                    <span ng-class='{"done":tsk.status}'>{{tsk.contents}}</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>


        <!-- <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click='clearCompleted()'>Clear Completed</button> -->
    </div>
    </div>

<script src='bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='bower_components/bootstrap-sass/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script>
    //angular parts
    var app = angular.module('TaskAPP',[]);

    //ajax sample
    app.controller("taskCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.colors = [
            {'title': 'red', 'color': '#e74c3c', 'status':true}, {'title': 'green', 'color': '#2ecc71', 'status':true}, {'title': 'amber', 'color': '#f39c12', 'status':true}
        ];

        //you are the problem
        var app = this;

        $http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/tasks/newtask")
          .success(function(data) {
            //the return is the tasks json file
            app.task = data;
          })


        app.addTask = function(task) {
            $http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/tasks/newtask", task)
              .success(function(data) {
                //the return is the tasks json file
                app.task = data;
              })
        }
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you really have a duplicate `task.save()` in your code?

Comment: @mscdex I forget comment it out, thanks man, but same issue existing

Comment: why dont you try https://github.com/mgonto/restangular? :)

Comment: @deadlock thanks for your suggestion and let me know there is a restangular, but this is not the solution, I've figure it out by myself already :)

Comment: I solved it by change `app.addTask(app.task)` and all the ng-model variables inside form to app.newtask, it's a normal variable name confuse problem